# TFS Automation Build generated publish files not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild

When we do a **manual build** to Dev, the application is working as expected and events are getting logged to Database.

But, when we do a build using **TFS Build Definition**, the application is working, but the events are not getting logged into database. What we have noticed is the bin folder in publish files being generated in manual build has a different size to that of AutomationBuild.

How do i solve this? Do i need to make some config changes or need to add some script commands to the Automation Build publish steps?

Comment: Did you mean the TFS build succeed without  any error/ warning info? What 's the result if you directly use MSBuild command in TFS build agent? Double check the size of bin folder is the same as TFS build /manual build or not. This will narrow down the issue. TFS build is also calling MSBuild command to do the build operation.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, I found the reason for this issue. In my project, we have external packages to install which deals with logging. But, those are missing in my build definition. That's the reason it's creating different size files

Comment: I would like to solve this by adding a nother build task, by using a command script. Could someone tell me a commandscript to add a package repo in packagemanager console.